# What events does WebKit fire, when a style attribute within a DOMSubTree changed?

Tags: javascript, webkit, gecko

With a Gecko based engine, the following example works and fires the appropriate event. Internet Explorer is covered with the onpropertychange event.

I'm using jQuery within this example, but need to access the "pure" event without jQuery as I want the solution to be as lightweight as possible. Timer based traversing the DOM/ChildElements is not a viable option (due to performance - ehm, lack of that is).

What does WebKit use? I'm testing with Linux Chromium and Win-Safari:

http://jsfiddle.net/eQErD/30/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is obviously: NONE.

See: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=8191

Due to performance reasons...

Nice one.

NOT.